# Is the example proposed by Microsoft for cryptography secure enough, or should I learn more?

Tags: cryptography, aes, rsa, hybrid

This is the article published by Microsoft for encrypting/decrypting data using RSA:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/walkthrough-creating-a-cryptographic-application

As a relatively new person into the cryptography world and having read a comment on stackoverflow saying that cryptography should use a hybrid model, I researched that and it seems that hybrid models use AES and RSA for encryption and I was wondering if the example provided by Microsoft fits into the hybrid model since it uses both and if is constructed well enough and not just for novice devs just venturing into the world of cryptography.

I already have a working example where an app would encode and another would decode by loading the private key file, similar to the example.

I found an article here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/834977/Using-RSA-and-AES-for-File-Encryption
He creates signatures and manifests and I'm wondering if this is what I'm looking for is Microsoft's example generally just enough, or weak?

PS: I removed the key container code and persistence as I don't want to persist or store my keys on the local machine, instead they are exported as standalone files to be stored in a DB maybe, so I'm not looking for opinions on that part at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> and not just for novice devs just venturing into the world of cryptography

Well, at least it tries to define some kind of protocol, although very sparse. It also uses CBC mode (implicitly, never a good idea) and RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for encryption. Most people would opt for OAEP if RSA is used and use an authenticated cipher such as GCM.

> I already have a working example where an app would encode and another would decode by loading the private key file, similar to the example.

Bad idea, the example is for file encryption, not for transport mode security, for which you need a secure transport protocol. Both the RSA implementation and CBC implementation are malleable, and are both susceptible to padding oracle attacks as well.

> I don't want to persist or store my keys on the local machine

You need to establish trust, something that is missing from the example. And to establish trust you **do** need to persist your keys, especially if they have been randomly generated.

---

In the end, asking if something is secure depends on context: you need to know what your goals are and then check if the protocol provides enough protection to achieve these goals.

This is also my problem with these generic examples or wrapper classes; they make no sense to me, as the generic security that they seem to provide may not fit your use case; I'd rather design a protocol *specific* to the use case.

Comment: Thank you, you provided me with few notions to explore. As to your question, my goal is to create an app that would designate a secure folder on my machine and encrypt everything inside it. Then another application to decrypt the folder when I need to use it. Nothing over the network all is local.